# How can I keep Consistency of two operations in one function with nodejs, express and mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, consistency

Recently, I write a nodejs application with express and mongoose.

When I update two collections in one function, the problem comes up.

Code segment is shown below.

```
exports.doVote = async (req, res) => {
  // some codes...

  // Operation 1
  const voteNumInfo = await VoteNumInfo.findOneAndUpdate({ activityId, vodId },
    { vodId, vodName, activityId, categoryId, categoryName, $inc: { voteNum: 1, showNum: 1 } },
    { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true });

  // Operation 2
  await VoteInfo.create({ vodId, vodName, activityId, categoryId, voteDate, stbId, ptag });

  // some codes...
}
```

where `VoteNumInfo` is a model for voting statistic, and `VoteInfo` is a model for voting record.

When the Operation 2 gets an error, the Operation 1 can not roll back.

Are there any solutions? Something like `@transaction` in Spring Framework?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB all operations to write are atomic at document level. That means that even if one write operation affects to several documents, each one will be atomic. Therefore, mongodb doesn't offer a way for transactions itself (more info in doc [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/))

The easy way to solve your problem, is to catch the exception, and if first query has been executed sucesfully and second one not, you can execute a query that undo the operation that you have executed previously (with $dec)

In Mongodb documentation, there is a pattern to solve this kind of situations, with states and so on, but probably in your case you don't need anything so complex. It is called the [Two-phase commit pattern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/). Take a look in case it helps.